# Autosuggest with Rest API issue on React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, autosuggest

I use `Autosuggest` component (https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest) in my `React` website. So, on the `onChange` event, I call `serviceOsago` to get the city/region/country data. Full data are too heavy to load at once, it takes about 10 seconds, so I get it partially by using `onChange` event. But the problem is when I type a city name for example: "Стрий", it does not add it to the `Autosuggest` and does not display it.

```
  const onChange = (event, {newValue, method}) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    serviceOsago.getCityCode(newValue).then((value:any) => {
      setCities(value);
    });
  };
```

When debugging it in the browser (Network -> Fetch/XHR), I found out it fails to add "Стрий" to Autosuggest due to request delay. For example, when I typed "Стрий", it still loads the "Стри" old call.

**Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {
  getErrorCity,
  getLoadingCity,
  getRegisterCity,
  setData,
  setError
} from '../../../redux-data/city/cityReducer';
import {getInstanceError} from '../../../utils/getInstanceError';
import theme from './AutoComplete.module.css';
import SquareLoader from 'react-spinners/SquareLoader';
import {config} from '../../../assets/config';
import serviceOsago from '../../../service/serviceOsago';

export const AutoComplete = (props) => {
  const [touch, setTouch] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const regCity = useSelector(getRegisterCity);
  const loading = useSelector(getLoadingCity);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([] as any[]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(regCity);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);

  const getSuggestions = (value, cities) => {
    let res = []; 
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;

    if (inputValue && inputLength > 0) {
        res = cities.filter(city => {
          return city.name.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(inputValue);
        });
    }

    return res;
  };

  const renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
    <div>
      {suggestion.nameFull}
    </div>
  );

  const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.nameFull;
  const error = useSelector(getErrorCity);
  const errors = {
    regCity: error
  };
  const {
    getClassError,
    getMessageError
  } = getInstanceError(errors);
  const mes = getMessageError('regCity');

  const onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    setSuggestions(getSuggestions(value, cities));
  };

  const onChange = (event, {newValue, method}) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    console.log(newValue);
    serviceOsago.getCityCode(newValue).then((value:any) => {
      setCities(value);
    });
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    setTouch(true);
    if (value === '') {
        dispatch(setError({
          message: 'Це поле обов\'язкове'
        }));
    }
  };

  const inputProps = {
    placeholder: 'Місто реєстрації автомобіля',
    value,
    onChange,
    onBlur,
    disabled: loading,
    id: props.id
  };

  const renderSuggestionInput = (inputProps) => (
    props.isAutoFocus ? <input {...inputProps} autoFocus /> : <input {...inputProps} />
  );

  const onSuggestionHighlighted = ({ suggestion }) => {
    //console.log(suggestion);
  };

  return (
    <div className={getClassError('regCity', touch)}>
      <Autosuggest 
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
        onSuggestionSelected={(event, data) => {
          dispatch(setData(data.suggestion));
        }}
        theme={theme}
        renderInputComponent={renderSuggestionInput}
        highlightFirstSuggestion={true}
        alwaysRenderSuggestions={true}
        onSuggestionHighlighted={onSuggestionHighlighted}
      />
      {mes && <p>{mes}</p>}
      <SquareLoader loading={loading} size={20} color={config.color} css={config.css}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Updated:** 22.07.2023

I think, there are two options how to fix this issue.

1. Load full data when website is loaded, save somewhere this data (for example: `localStorage`) and add it to `Autosuggest`, so it will be available when user is typing. But I think `localStorage` will fail to save 12 - 15 MB of data. There must be another way to store huge data in `React/TypeScript`?
2. Change/improve the `onChange` event, so it will only trigger `API` request when a user finished typing and get the full city word instead of calling request on every character. Is it possible to override the `onChange` event?

What is the proper way to add data from `REST API` to `Autosuggest` when a user typing data in `React/TypeScript`? Thank you.

Comment: do you mean the API is not getting called with new input?

Comment: @sid
Yes, it still loads the old one. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: @sid
Is it possible to save in localStorage -> 12 - 15 MB of data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have fixed this issue by using `setTimeout` function and `useEffect`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const delayCityRequest = setTimeout(() => {
      if (value.length > 0) {
          console.log(value);
          serviceOsago.getCityCode(value).then((cities: any) => {
            setCities(cities);
            setSuggestions(getSuggestions(value, cities));
          });
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(delayCityRequest);
  }, [value]);
```

This will allow to intercept the user typing and send request only after 1 second. Now, it works well. This issue is resolved. Thank you.